# Updating values in dynamic array - Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, arrays

I need to add a number to existing value in array under index 'id'. I have the following code:

```
 contract Store {

  uint256[] public totalamt;

  function append(uint256 id,uint price) payable{

    totalamt[id] = totalamt[id] + price;

}

   }
```

Array is not initialized.Each time I need to update the array.Help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're better off with a `mapping`. It does exactly what you want.

Here's how:

```
contract Store {

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public totalamt;

    function append(uint256 id,uint price) payable public {

        totalamt[id] = totalamt[id] + price;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use storage key word instead of memory for your variable

```
    struct info {
      string Name;
      string LastName;
    }

    info[] public data;
    uint256 count = 0;

    function add(string memory name, string memory lastName) public payable {
        data.push(info(name, lastName));
        count++;
    }

    function edit(
        uint256 index,
        string memory name,
        string memory lastName
    ) public payable {
        require(index < count, "out of array");
        info storage item = data[index];
        item.Name = name;
        item.LastName = lastName;
        count++;
    }
```